# Difference between approaching and being exactly a number

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

When we take a limit, we say that the value is never equals that number, but approaches it, like in
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0.$$
It never reaches $0$, but becomes closer and closer to $0$.

In this case, isn't it wrong to say things like:

$$2 = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}+\cdots $$
Or that a derivative of $\sin(x)$ is $\cos(x)$ since the limit of $$\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x)-\sin(x)}{\Delta x}$$
with $\Delta x$ approaching $0$ is never **equal** to $\cos(x)$ but **infinitely closer**?

Is there a good article about this that I can read and understand it better?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$ is equal to $1$, not $2$.

Comment: I do not understand in the answers why .999999999... has limit of 1 but never equals one if we know that it does equal?

Comment: @Val: $0.\bar{9}$ is indeed equal to $1$. But since you can't do calculations with infinitely many $9$'s by hand or by computers, you have to cut the number after some number of terms and that number isn't equal to $1$ anymore, only an approximation of it. But if $9$'s are repeated infinitely the number is indeed equal to $1$. Actually what you're talking about can be interpreted as $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} (\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{9}{10^{-k}})=1$ Look at Zev Chonoles' answer for a great explanation of the confusion people have about the limit of a sequence and the terms of the sequence.

Comment: @some1.new4u You're right, I've forgot the 1

Comment: @Val: .9999... *doesn't* have limit 1. It doesn't even make sense to ask for the limit of .9999.... It *does* make sense to ask for the limit of the sequence .9, .99, .999, .9999, et cetera, and that sequence has limit 1. However, .9999... is just a single number whose value happens to be equal to the limit of that sequence. So .9999... is just one.

Comment: @some1: You *can* do calculations by hand with infinitely many 9's: you just have to use some means other than the arithmetic of terminating decimals to do so. You already demonstrated one notation that is convenient for this purpose.

Comment: $0.\bar{9} = 1$ is something that causes a lot of confusion and argumentation. It took me a while to reach this conclusion, but I think it's actually quite simple: nobody said that the decimal notation system had to have a 1:1 correspondence to every member of $\mathbb{Q}$. Some numbers have more than one representation.

Answer (score 24):

Let's look at your sentence

> It never reaches $0$, but becomes closer and closer to $0$.

This is imprecise, and this is at the center of your confusion. What is "it"? There is an important distinction to be made:

- The ***sequence*** $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots$ never reaches $0$, but becomes closer and closer to $0$.
- Let $L$ be the ***limit*** of the sequence $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots$. Then $L$ is *exactly equal* to $0$.

Comment: +1: exactly.  Sequences (and functions) approach limits.  A limit itself is just a number.

Comment: I know that the limit is defined as the number that the sequence approaches. But if we think of the derivative as the exact number of the difference $\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x) - \sin(x)}{\Delta x}$ with $\Delta x$ approaching $0$ (forget definition of limits and other things, just think about this difference when $\Delta x$ gets closer to $0$), then it will never be exactly $\cos(x)$ but closer and closer to it. Then we cannot say that $2 = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + ...$ but almost exactly this sum.

Comment: @Mr.Zantos: ... and if I think a cat is a dog, I'll be awfully confused when people tell me that it meows rather than barks. Thinking of the derivative as the exact number of a difference quotient is simply *wrong*. While it's good to develop some concept of a difference quotient that varies as $\Delta x$ approaches 0, it's bad to conflate that concept with the derivative.

Comment: @Hurkyl But the fact that the limit of a sequence is defined to have an exact value, it doesn't means that the sum $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...$ is exactly equal to $2$ just because its limit is equal to $2$. I don't care about the word 'limit'.

Comment: @Mr.Zantos: There is no such thing as "the sum $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$" **other than the "limit"**.  The **definition** of the value of an infinite series is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\;\overset{\text{by definition}}{=}\;\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

The point is that the limit is exactly the operation that takes a sequence $x_n$ approaching $x$ and gives you $x$. That is, when we say $$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x,$$ we mean that $x_n$ converges to $x$ as $n\to \infty$; this does *not* claim that $x_n = x$ for any $n$. In your sum, the ellipsis $\cdots$ implies a limiting process: this equation could be more formally written

$$ 1 = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \frac 1 {2^n}.$$

Note that none of these finite sums is equal to $1$, but they approach $1$, so we say *their limit is* 1.

Comment: So when we say that the the expression $\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x)-\sin(x)}{\Delta x}$ is becoming closer to $\cos(x)$ when $\Delta x$ becomes closer to $0$, we cannot say that $\sin'(x)$ is exactly equal to $\cos(x)$ but closer and closer to it.

Comment: @Mr.Zantos: $\sin'(x)$ is defined as the *limit* of that expression as $\Delta x \to 0$. That expression is never equal to $\cos(x)$, but it converges to it; and thus its *limit* (which we called $\sin'(x)$) is exactly equal to $\cos(x)$.

Comment: I know that the derivative is defined as the limit of that thing with $\Delta x$ aproaching $0$, but without thinking in limits, we should understand the slope of a function as the exact value of that difference, wich in this case is not equal to $\cos(x)$, but almost it.

Comment: @Mr.Zantos: the slope of a *linear* function is the exact difference quotient. Since we are dealing with a non-linear function, to find the slope of the tangent line we can approximate by difference quotients with very small $\Delta x$; but to get the slope of the actual tangent line we must take the limit.

Comment: Yep but I cannot admit that this difference with $\Delta x$ getting closer to $0$ is exactly equals the limit :(

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that we say $\forall \epsilon>0 :|x-y|<\epsilon$. I want to claim that if this is true for any arbitrary positive $\epsilon$ then it forces $|x-y|$ to be zero.

Suppose that $|x-y|$ is not zero but it is very very small, so, there exists a natural number $n$ such that

$$\exists n\in\mathbb{N}:\displaystyle \frac{1}{10^{-(n+1)}} <|x-y|< \frac{1}{10^{-n}}$$

Now we can set $\displaystyle \epsilon<\frac{1}{10^{-(n+1)}}$ and that contradicts $|x-y|<\epsilon$. So, because $|x-y|<\epsilon$ is true for any $\epsilon>0$, no matter how small $\epsilon$ is we know $|x-y|=0 \implies x-y=0 \implies x=y$. This is because there is no smallest positive real number. And because $|x-y|$ is non-negative, then if it's not zero, we'll have a contradiction, so it must be zero.

This is true for limits too. When you say $\displaystyle 2=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$ this is an equality. But if you consider only a finitely many terms of this series then that is only an approximation of $2$.

Comment: To make what I said clearer, when you talk about limit in sequences, you say that no matter how small you want epsilon to be, you can always take $n$ large enough that it happens. So it's always possible to say $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ for some natural numbers $n$ that are large enough. In other words you can think of it this way $|a_\infty - L|<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ which forces $a_\infty = L$. Even though I don't like description very much but it explains what's happening I think.

Answer (score 2):

No, limit of $$\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x)-\sin(x)}{\Delta x}$$
with $\Delta x$ approaching $0$ is **equal** to $\cos(x)$. But $\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x)-\sin(x)}{\Delta x}$ is never equal to $\cos(x)$.
and also note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16}+\cdots$, but $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2^k}$ is never equal to $2$.

Comment: I know this is exactly equals to $\cos(x)$ because the limit is defined as the value that the function gets closer and closer to it. But I don't know why whe should assume that the difference of $\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x)-\sin(x)}{\Delta x}$ with $\Delta x$ approaching $0$ is exactly equal to $\cos(x)$, because this will never be equal to $\cos(x)$ but closer and closer to it.

Comment: Derivative of $\sin(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x)-\sin(x)}{\Delta x}=\cos(x)$ and Differential of $\sin(x)=\sin'(x)dx=\cos(x)dx$. You must define difference of $\frac{\sin(x+\Delta x)-\sin(x)}{\Delta x}$. It does seem that "difference" is an Imprecise expression.

Answer (score 2):

when you are approaching a number(a->5), it means that you are hypothetically so close to the number, that it is practically possible to treat it =5.
derivative means a small change in x, with respect to a small change in y.

since y=sin(x). 
and we know that slope(derivative in nothing but finding the slope) =(y2-y1)/(x2-x1),therefore dy/dx=(sin(x+small change in x)-sin(x))/small change in x

Answer (score 2):

Sometime early on, we learn about binary sums: things like 3+7.

Soon after, we learn ternary sums: things like 7+13+8. What could this possibly mean? Well, we might say it means we first compute 7+13 to get 20, then 20+8 to get 28. Or maybe we'll mean we should add 13+8 to get 21, then 7+21 to get 28. Of course, we quickly learn that we get the same answer either way, no matter what the numbers are.

But one day, we face a quaternary sum: something like 1+2+3+4. What could *this* mean? Well, we can give the same solution: we keep applying binary sums to pairs of numbers until we get one left.

This method will continue to work with 5-ary sums, 6-ary sums, or even $n$-ary sums for any natural number $n \geq 1$. (and it is fruitful to define a 0-ary sum too, but that's another topic)

Then one fateful day, we see a sum like
$$ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots $$
What could *this* possibly mean? We might try to adopt the familiar convention that we add numbers in pairs until we have one left, but that doesn't work here. While most approaches to the problem would say that this sum has the same value as
$$ \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots $$
we still have infinitely many terms: we haven't gotten any closer to getting a single number.

So we need to understand an infinite sum in some other fashion. We might even be interested in there being multiple different ways to understand it, depending upon just what we are trying to use them for.

Introductory calculus gives the first rigorous definition most people encounter. We define a sequence of *partial* sums:

- 1
- $1 + \frac{1}{2}$
- $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}$
- $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8}$
- $\vdots$

and then we  "the value of a calculus-style infinite sum" *means* the same thing as "the limit of this sequence".

Other summations methods are possible. Even different approaches to the calculus-style sum are possible.

For example, if we have some multi-set of positive numbers $X$, we might want to define their sum. Because we desire that if $S \subset X$, we should insist that the sum of $S$ be less than the sum of $X$, we could make the following definition:

- $\sum X$ is defined to be the smallest real number with the property that $\sum S \leq \sum X$ for every finite subset $S \subseteq X$.

where $\sum S$ for a finite set $S$ is defined in the usual way (repeatedly add numbers pairwise until you have one left).

It turns out that $\sum X$ is the same value as the calculus-style infinite sum I described above.

---

Another approach is somewhat more algebraic in nature. We don't care what an infinite sum is, so long as it satisfies some 'obvious' properties: e.g.

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots =
1 + \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots \right) $$
$$ 2 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdots \right) 
= \left(2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{8} + \cdots \right) $$

For the infinite geometric sum, we can then solve these equations to get

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots = 2$$

without any notion of limits even being involved!